# После переустановки Windows

Tags: cmd

Установил новую Windows 7 MAX после её установки вылазит диспетчер загрузки, и просит что бы я выбрал операционную систему, хотя в msconfig я заходил, но там только одна Windows, пробовал удалить папку Windows.old, из диска С, но и там отказало в доступе, что делать? Помогите!

Answer (score 2):

1. Возможно ли, что у вас просто недостаточно прав? попробуйте запустить msconfig "от имени администратора"
2. Возможно та же проболема при удалении папки Windows.old, попробуйте повысить себе привелегии
3. Попробуйте загрузку с livecd и удаление Windows.old
4. Форматирование диска (создание раздела с NTFS заново) при установке ОС.